# Android FULL_WAKE_LOCK is deprecated but PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK is not deprecated

Tags: android, wakelock, android-wake-lock

Here i mentioned the code for waking up the screen. i want the code is listen still the app is closed and the cpu is cleared and user can click the power button when ever my screen is unlock the app is sync like whatsapp.

```
    PowerManager pm =  (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE); 
    wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "whatever");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    wl.acquire();
```

Answer (score 7):

**FULL_WAKE_LOCK** is already deprecated and it's better to use the **PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK**. This is the standard way to do this,

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
Wakelock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
        "MyWakelockTag");
wakeLock.acquire();
```

For more way of implementation kindly visit the official link,

https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html

Comment: Actually i want my app is working on under background also like whatsapp,hike any other method is available...

Comment: You can do that easily. Just implement a service and don't destroy while the user closes the app. Meanwhile use the WAKE_LOCK which will keep the service alive even after running in background

Comment: it is work when the process killed also it is working

Comment: It's not working on Android 8.
Also adding `wakeLock.release();` to `onDestroy()` not helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can consider an alternate, using JobScheduler for running background tasks while the app is still sleep for longer time thus preserving the battery. 
JobScheduler provides many methods to define job-execution conditions, therefore we can leverage that but it can be used for apps which are using Android 5.0 (API level 21) & above.

Comment: We are coding code, not literature. Can you please post code?

Comment: Try this to safely implement a bg task without losing device's battery life and performance 
https://android.jlelse.eu/modern-background-execution-in-android-bfae13c61b6b

Comment: thank you for comment. It's so hard without any examples. I spent 2 days to explain JobScheduler and it not take effect on Oreo+ api..